# Adding related entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-4.0

I have these 2 tables,

```
Student
(Id, Name, DOB)
School
(Id, name)

Table 3
(student.Id, School.Id, expiryDate)
```

I need to ADD, new student, new school and create new record for table 3)

Is there a way I can do this through entity framework?

Comment: What have you got so far? Model (code first?), first attempts, failures? Betters details = better answers.

Comment: well i don't know where to start, I need to add student and school, and then create 3rd table with studentId.

Comment: most important thing i need is new Id for the student and the course, so i can add new 3rd table

Comment: @Gert The homework tag is deprecated, please stop using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got a model in Entity Framework, generated from a database. If so, it should show three classes, `Student`, `School` and the junction table "Table 3", probably `StudentSchool`, probably with navigation properties `StudentSchool.School` and `StudentSchool.Student`

As an aside, if your "Table 3" only had the two key value and not expiryDate, EF would have mapped school and student only with a pure many-to-many association between them (`School.Students` and `Student.Schools`).

You can just create three objects, `School`, `Student`, and `StudentSchool`, set the navigation properties of the latter, save, and EF will figure out the correct order of inserts and set the foreign keys.

(Another assumption: your tables have identity columns as primary keys).

Answer (score 0):

what you describe is known as a many-to-many relationship. googling "entity framework many to many" will bring back the results you need. here is just one example.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First

Comment: as @GertArnold commented above better details = better answers. in this case you now have the terminology necessary to search to the answers you need.